# When using a question word order to make a sentence more emphatic, should the sentence be affirmative or negative?

Tags: sentence-structure

Which sentence is correct?

"We talked on the phone for hours. Man does she like me!"

Or

"We talked on the phone for hours. Man doesn't she like me!"

Just to clarify, the intent is to say "she likes me a lot."

Comment: #1 is correct but #2 means the same thing in some dialects. English is funny like that.

Comment: Opposites can be synonyms, in the vernacular.  In reply to, "Think she likes me?", "fat chance," and "slim chance," both mean *no*. That's rather ironical.